# FBX SDK exporting into older fbx file format

Tags: c++, fbx

FBX SDK 2016.0 by default writes FBX files with new format, incompatible with previous SDK version. There is a note about it in a readme:

> Updated file format to 7.5 (compatible with 2016+ products) which now
>   uses 64bit integers in the binary block headers to allow for large file
>   support (>2GB). These new FBX files will NOT import in older products
>   (2015 or less), so make sure you set the right export format if you need
>   to target these older products.

But I can't find a way to "set the right export format" in my code to export into previous format.

Tried this in my export setup code with no luck:

```
fbx_manager_->GetIOSettings()->SetIntProp( 
    EXP_FBX_EXPORT_FILE_VERSION, FBX_FILE_VERSION_7400 );
```

What is a correct way to request saving with older format version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am probably late, but I've found the solution:
There is method `FbxExporter::SetFileExportVersion()` which takes a string constant as an argument. Constats can be found in fbxio.h and look like `FBX_2014_00_COMPATIBLE`